# How to construct a contractible space but not locally path connected?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, connectedness

I am looking for a space which is contractible and not locally path connected.

I know the cone $CX$ of every space $X$  is contractible. Besides, it seems that if $X$ is locally path connected, so is $CX$. Therefore, I need to find a space which is not locally path connected.

Therefore, I tried $\sin(1/x)$-space and considered its cone.

Since $X$ can be topologically embedded in $CX$, $\sin(1/x)$-space is a subspace of its cone. It seems that open subsets of a locally path connected space are again locally path connected. However, $X$ is not open in $CX$.

Therefore, I am not sure whether it is locally path connected or not.

Any help will be appreciated. (I prefer some simple examples of such spaces, since I am a beginner in algebraic topology.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is not locally path-connected, then there is a point $x$ and a neighborhood $U$ of $x$, which does not contain a path-connected neighborhood. Now choose $0<\epsilon<1$. The subspace $U\times[0,ϵ)$ of $X\times I$ is also a subspace of the cone $C(X)$. If it had a path-connected neighborhood $V$ of $(x,0)$, then the projection of $V$ onto $X\times\{0\}$ would be a path-connected neighborhood of $x$ within $U$ (since the projection is continuous and open). That's why the cone isn't locally path-connected either.

On the other hand, if $X$ is locally (path-)connected, then so is $X\times I$ as $I$ is locally path-connected. This property then carries over to the cone $C(X)$ since quotient maps preserve local (path-)connectedness.

Answer (score 7):

The union of all the lines $y = mx$ with $m \in \mathbb Q$ with the topology of subspace of $\mathbb R^2$ is a contractible space but is not locally path connected.

The verification of the properties are trivial.

Comment: Thank you very much! By the way, can you give me an example by using the cone? In other words, can you show me a space $X$ such that $CX$ is an example? I am really curious about this. Thank you again.

Comment: Actually the space that I'm pretty sure that if you intersect the space above with the closed unitary ball of $\mathbb R^2$ you should find a contractible space non locally path connected which is a cone. The space $X$ should be the intersection of space in the answer with the unit circle.