# Hypothesis concerning existence of universal cover

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I've got some doubts about the hypothesis concerning the existence of a universal cover for a space.

More precisely, from Hatcher's book I know that:

> Every path connected, locally path connected, semi locally simple connected space admits a universal cover.

Moreover I found out without proof that:

> Every path connected, locally contractible space admits an universal cover.

The confusion comes from the fact that we know that if a space is locally contractible then it doesn't necessary implies it to be locally path connected, for example: [How to construct a contractible space but not locally path connected?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/547171/how-to-construct-a-contractible-space-but-not-locally-path-connected)

Is there something wrong with the second statement? If not, could somebody point to a proof of it?

Thanks

Comment: *Locally* contractible does imply locally path connected. Any contractible neighborhood is also path connected.

Comment: You are right, thanks! I hadn't properly read the link I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $X$ is path-connected and locally contractible.

Then let $x$ be in $X$, and $O$ any open set containing $x$, and let $U_x$ be a contractible neighbourhood of $x$ such that $U_x \subseteq O$.

As a contractible space is path-connected, $U_x$ is path-connected. It follows
that $X$ is locally path-connected. Also, any loop on inside $U_x$ starting in $x$ can be continuously be contracted to $x$, by a homotopy $U_x \times [0,1] \to U_x$, as $U_x$ is contractible. So by definition (e.g. see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-locally_simply_connected), we only require the homotopy to be defined with codomain $X$) $X$ is semi-locally simply connected.

Now the quoted theorem in Hatcher allows us to state that $X$ has a universal cover.